# How to trigger on Validation.HasError to change checkbox background color?

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, binding

I have a checkbox in XAML as:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>


<CheckBox  Content="Cash Only" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="158,0,0,264" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="83" IsThreeState="True" >
        <CheckBox.IsChecked>
            <Binding Path="ServiceBilling.CashOnly">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <h:Not_Null_Rule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </CheckBox.IsChecked>
    </CheckBox>
```

The Not_Null_Rule correctly returns false if the checkbox IsChecked property is null and true otherwise.

However, when null, the checkbox shows a grayed-out checkmark inside the box. The box has a red-border, but is not filled in Red.

What am I doing wrong? I'd like the box to be filled Red when it is null.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone interested, the answer to this newbie's question is a lot more involved then it would first appear.

1. In studying the checkbox styles, there is no dependency property for the Border Background which is itself contained within the BulletDecorator. Hence, the only way to get to it is as @MohitShrivastava suggested and replace the default style with OverridesDefaultStyle. [See Customizing the Checkbox](http://www.eidias.com/Blog/2012/6/1/custom-wpf-check-box-with-inner-shadow-effect)
2. It appears that validation ultimately comes down to an AdornedElementPlaceholder which, AFAIK does not expose any of the properteries of the held element.[See How to apply style to an adorned element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703701/wpf-how-to-apply-style-to-adornedelementplaceholders-adornedelement).

So, in lieu of a better idea, here is my working code. Better suggestions are welcome.

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Foreground="Red" FontSize="12pt">!!!</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Foreground="Red" FontSize="12pt">!!!</TextBlock>
                <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
                </Border>
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>

 <CheckBox  
            Content="Cash Only" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="202,0,0,264" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
            Width="108" FontSize="16"
            Style="{StaticResource WarningCheckbox}"  Validation.ErrorTemplate="{DynamicResource validationTemplate}"
             >
            <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                <Binding Path="ServiceBilling.CashOnly" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <h:Not_Null_Rule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </CheckBox.IsChecked>

        </CheckBox>

 <!--Warning CheckBox to show Red when null-->
  <Style x:Key="WarningCheckbox" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"    Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"  Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"       Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"            Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
          <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
            <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
              <Border x:Name="Border"
                        Width="18"
                        Height="18"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        ClipToBounds="True">
                <Border.Effect>
                  <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" ShadowDepth="2" />
                </Border.Effect>
                <Path x:Name="CheckMark"
                        Width="18"
                        Height="18"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Data="M 0 0 L 8 8 M 0 8 L 8 0"
                        Stretch="Fill"
                        Stroke="Black"
                        StrokeEndLineCap="Round"
                        StrokeStartLineCap="Round"
                        StrokeThickness="2" />
              </Border>
           </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
               <ContentPresenter Margin="4,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
          </BulletDecorator>
          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Stroke" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
              <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
              <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
              <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>

            <!--
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
              <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>-->
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
              <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
              <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Stroke" Value="Gray" />
            </Trigger>
          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this style to accomplish the task

You need to change the colors according to your need

```
<Style TargetType="CheckBox" x:Key="CircleCheckbox">
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>   
        <Setter Property="Content" Value=""></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">                   
                    <Grid>                     
                        <Ellipse x:Name="outerEllipse">
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <RadialGradientBrush>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Red"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.88" Color="LightCoral"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="DarkRed"/>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <Ellipse Margin="10" x:Name="highlightCircle" >
                            <Ellipse.Fill >
                                <LinearGradientBrush >
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Green"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="LightGreen"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="DarkGreen"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="content" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="highlightCircle" Property="Fill">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.3,0" EndPoint="0.7,1">
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Green"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="LightGreen"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="DarkGreen"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter TargetName="outerEllipse" Property="Fill">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Green"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0.88" Color="LightGreen"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="DarkGreen"/>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="highlightCircle" Property="Fill">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.3,0" EndPoint="0.7,1">
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Red"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="LightCoral"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="DarkRed"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

You can also have a look on the **[Default Template of CheckBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319(v=vs.85).aspx)** to get the better idea what you wanted to do with the checkbox

Comment: So I need to remake the entire control template to set triggers ???? That seems extensive :(   Thanks.

Comment: Anyway to use Validation.HasError in my opening clause?